# Getfilter ( ) возвращает всегда первую строку в ListView? (Android)

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Есть список из объекта ToDodocument.

[image]

Есть поле Edittext. Когда ввожу символ он должен фильтровать мне список. Но работает вот как.[image]

Он всегда возвращает только первый пункт. Почему так работает.

Вот где происходит сортировка при нажатии на клавишу.

private class TextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        **adapter.getFilter().filter(s);**

    }

}
```

В Adapter метод getFilter не переопределял, т.к. я думаю он должен работать. Но почему так криво работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по умолчанию он будет работать, если правильно переопределить `toString()` твоих объектов в адаптере

Comment: Да я переоределил. 

public String toString() {
  return name;
 } и все ровно не пашет((((

Comment: ты используешь ArrayAdapter? Врятли, так бы работало =) ну тогда используй или ArrayAdapter или лучше напиши свой фильтер

Comment: Да использую ArrayAdapter 

Вот public class ToDoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoDocument>

Comment: Покажите код адаптера